# Harry Potter and Percy Jackson Fanfiction where Percy has a sister Andromeda. She is the daughter of Neptune

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, percy-jackson

I am looking for a Harry Potter and Percy Jackson fanfiction. I think the title might be Daughter of Rome. I believe it was posted on fanfiction.net

Here is what I remember:

- Percy had a sister named Andromeda
- She was a daughter of Neptune
- She was taken and raised by a Black
- Harry was related to the Jackson
- Harry was a descendant of Thanatos
- Andromeda was born with a weak heart and she was made immortal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a story called 'Daughter of Rome'. It's not available to read on FanFiction.net, but is archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150928190243/https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10082297/1/Daughter-of-Rome).

> Andromeda was no ordinary girl, but what she would have never anticipated was immortality or becoming so involved with the Greek side of things, because she had no love for Greece, that could be certain. But it was a bit more difficult to hate Greece when her own brother and friend were of its bloodline. Why couldn't she have been a normal demigod and not Neptune's daughter?

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is the story I was looking for.

Comment: You can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].